# Trying to add a shipping calculation rule using "Order Address component comparison" condition

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm attempting to create a basic "Shipping rate by country" Calculation rule in Drupal Commerce using the Flat Rate shipping module.

I've followed the official tutorial for this exact thing ([here](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce1/user-guide/shipping/calculating-flat-rate-based-on-customers-shipping-address)) but run into a problem when I attempt to add the "Order address component comparison" Condition. I simply get a "No order addresses could be found for comparison." error and the Address dropdown is empty (see screenshot below).

I've been unable to find any references to this error. I added Commerce to an existing Drupal 7 site so I'm wondering if I missed a piece of configuration somewhere. Other than that every other aspect of the store runs fine.

[image: Address selection is empty]

Comment: What did you select under _Data selectors_ (which isn't shown in the screenshot)?

Comment: The Data Selectors pane doesnt have any inputs, it just shows possible options which can be used in the Data selector field. - https://imgur.com/eYGqTCp